# How to use drush with proxy

Tags: drush, proxies

I am using Acquia Dev Desktop 2 for my Drupal 8 project, I tried to download module with Drush. But I can only access the internet via a proxy. How can I configure drush to use the correct http proxy settings for downloading?

Answer (score 6):

Drush by default is using `wget` to download project (if available), otherwise `curl`. This can be change by `--package-handler`. You can check which package handler is in place by running your command with debug parameter (`-d`).

So you configure proxy the same way as you would configure this for `wget` or `curl`.

For wget, you can configure these lines in `~/.wgetrc`:

```
use_proxy = on
https_proxy = http://proxy-host:8080
http_proxy = http://proxy-host:8080
```

<sup>Note: Please check `/usr/local/etc/wgetrc` for some examples.</sup>

For `curl` this line should in your `~/.curlrc`:

```
proxy=http://username:password@proxy-host:port
```

For both I think you can try to export `http_proxy`/`https_proxy` as a system variable.

Comment: Please where would I find these setting (Wget and Curl)

Comment: @GoodTaofiq You've to create a new files in your HOME user directory. Check `/usr/local/etc/wgetrc` for example, read `man wget` or Google for some sample files.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't answer the question of how to get drush to work on Acquia Dev Desktop under Windows, cf [my question here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207549/how-to-configure-drush-with-acquia-devdesktop-on-windows-to-access-through-proxy?rq=1)

Comment: For the record : drush 8 provide the " --update-backend" option that could be set to drush (default) which used wget to fetch update (hence use kenorb answer) or drupal which use the core update module (you have to enable it and set the $settings['http_client_config']['proxy']* options in settings.php.